# JPA specification for Joda-Time comparison

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jodatime

I am trying to get orders specific to a range using JPA specifications.

Please find below code and my domain class. Date types are from Joda-Time, but unable to match with that date though.

```
public static Specification<BnvOrder> byStatusChangedDateRange(String statusName, String fromDate, String toDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
        LocalDateTime fromDateTime = format.parseLocalDateTime(fromDate);
//      LocalDateTime toDateTime = format.parseLocalDateTime(toDate+" 00:00:00");
        return new Specification<BnvOrder>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<BnvOrder> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

//              return cb.and(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<LocalDateTime>get(statusName), fromDateTime),
//                      cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<LocalDateTime>get(statusName), toDateTime));
//              cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo("DATE("+root.get("deliveryEndDate")+")", fromDateTime);
                return cb.between(root.get("deliveryEndDate"),fromDateTime,fromDateTime);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Actually It is working fine for me, if its LocalDateTime datatype

Comment: Is it really `BETWEEN fromDateTime AND fromDateTime` (same parameter)? In that case you don't really have a range, but a single point. Provide more info  what's your actual problem - do you get an exception or it does not find the data that you expect to be find? If the latter, show an example of the data and query parameters.